# amChart color for highest and lowest column

Tags: javascript, amcharts

We are working with amCharts. By using serial chart with columns, I want to set different colors for the highest and lowest values.

Somebody knows how is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  time I found the solution in the [documentation](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts). We can do that by adding a field in the `dataProvider`, e.g. `columnColor` with value and setting the `colorField` of the `graph` to `'columnColor'` (we also have the possibility to set the `lineColorField`).

**UPDATE:**

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3ypB/228/)